# How to control what Observables to run in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I hope you can help me to understand my problem, I have a problem with RXJS and Angular, I try to avoid that the call of an observable is activated using an if condition but in the execution of my website it is executed even if the condition is false, I have a service (_chatService) that is in charge of making the HTTP requests, the findChatMessage() method is called and it returns me an observable, I have another webSocket service that informs me when I get a notification, within this Observable I have the condition, that allows me to know if the notification I received is for current conversation, and then run the method findChatMessage().

I don't know what I am doing wrong since I am new in Angular
Thank you very much

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._router.paramMap.subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res.has('idConversation')) {
          var localIdConversation = res.get('idConversation');

          if (typeof localIdConversation === 'string') {
            this._chatService.findChatMessages(localIdConversation, this._authService.getCurrentUsername()).subscribe(
              resp => {
                if (typeof localIdConversation === 'string') {
                  this.messages = resp;
                  this.setMessageFields(localIdConversation);
                  // update bagde
                  this._webSocketClientService.notificationReceived.next(true);
                }
            });

            this._webSocketClientService.notificationMessage.subscribe(
                notif => {
                  if (notif.idConversation == localIdConversation) {
                    console.log("---> " + localIdConversation);
                    console.log("inside subscribe");
                    this._chatService.findChatMessage(notif.idChatNotif).subscribe(
                      message => {
                        this.messages.push(message);
                        this._webSocketClientService.notificationReceived.next(true);
                      }
                    );
                  }
                }
              );
          }
        }
      },
      error => console.log('something wrong occurred: ' + error)
    );
  }
```

The findChatMessage method within the ChatService file

```js
findChatMessage(idMessage:number): Observable<IMessage>{
    const URL: string = environment.url_base + '/messages/' + idMessage;
    return this._http.get<IMessage>(URL);
  }
```

Comment: I believe you are in need of the filter method.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the right way to work with `rxjs`.

You **must** use operators, there are many of them, each solves some particular problem well. In your case `localIdConversation: string` is observed and each time new `localIdConversation` comes you want:

1. Cancel any in-flight request that could be in progress right now (to avoid race conditions).
2. Trigger `findChatMessage` with newly came parameters (to get new data and be able to use it somehow).

So roughly it gonna look something like

```
const conversationStreams = localIdConversationStream.pipe(
    tap(console.debug), // prints to console
    switchMap(localIdConversation => {
        return findChatMessage(localIdConversation, anyOtherParametersThatYouMightNeed...);
    }))
```

...and then, when you need to, you `conversationStreams.subscribe()` to run the pipe and make things happen.

That's what [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) is designed for.